# How to run external program in Mac OS via C++?

Tags: c++, macos

I need to build a cross platform that need to call an external .jar application. I could do it in Windows, but I have no idea how to do it in Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use this instead:

```
system("/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari");
```

You would get a new instance of Safari. Much like opening multiple instances of IE in Windows. But this isn't Mac behavior so use "open" instead.

Comment: How does this run a jar file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open Safari, use this:

```
system("open /Applications/Safari.app");
```